# Android - can we open camera in one activity and use it in another

Tags: android, camera

guys. I want to make a game in which I want to start camera when play button is pressed. There is a problem - it takes too long to open the camera (5-6 seconds). So can I open the camera when the user is in the options menu and when he/she press play button just to get the camera and put the camera view where I want. In that way the user would not wait 5-6 second. 
And if there is no way to do this, I can just write "Loading ..." with some picture while the camera is loading, but how can I understand when the camera is ready to remove "Loading..." ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The latter can be handled in onActivityResult().

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you explain it in more details, I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by zgc7009 in more detail: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

As for me, you can initialize camera when your application has started. Just set your SurfaceView invisible or gone. When the user clicks play button set SurfaceView like visible. In this case you don't wait.